# Pentaho PDI ETL - Get file with FTP not working

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pdi

I am searching since days for a solution of my problem.

i am running Pentaho PDI CE 9.4.0.0-343 on a windows system.
I have prepared a very simple job with Start-Get file with FTP-success steps.

If i am running the job locally everything is working fine, if i transfer the job to the carte server i always get the same error below:

```
2023/11/23 21:07:28 - Pentaho FTP hourly_shotdata - Start of job execution
2023/11/23 21:07:28 - Pentaho FTP hourly_shotdata - Starting entry [Get a file with FTP]
2023/11/23 21:07:28 - Get a file with FTP - Started FTP job to 10.161.96.91
2023/11/23 21:07:58 - Get a file with FTP - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Unexpected error : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [17, 1) out of bounds for length 17
2023/11/23 21:07:58 - Get a file with FTP - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Error getting files from FTP : Success condition was broken! We have 1 error(s)
2023/11/23 21:07:58 - Pentaho FTP hourly_shotdata - Finished job entry [Get a file with FTP] (result=[false])
2023/11/23 21:07:58 - Pentaho FTP hourly_shotdata - Job execution finished
```

i am a little bit helpless after days of finding a solution and hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks, Armin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
  <name>Pentaho FTP hourly_shotdata</name>
  <description/>
  <extended_description/>
  <job_version/>
  <job_status>0</job_status>
  <directory>/</directory>
  <created_user>-</created_user>
  <created_date>2019/11/08 12:30:59.069</created_date>
  <modified_user>-</modified_user>
  <modified_date>2019/11/08 12:30:59.069</modified_date>
  <parameters>
    </parameters>
  <slaveservers>
    <slaveserver>
      <name>Carte</name>
      <hostname>localhost</hostname>
      <port>8081</port>
      <webAppName/>
      <username>cluster</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <proxy_hostname/>
      <proxy_port/>
      <non_proxy_hosts/>
      <master>Y</master>
      <sslMode>N</sslMode>
    </slaveserver>
    <slaveserver>
      <name>CarteServer</name>
      <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
      <port>8080</port>
      <webAppName/>
      <username>cluster</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <proxy_hostname/>
      <proxy_port/>
      <non_proxy_hosts/>
      <master>Y</master>
      <sslMode>N</sslMode>
    </slaveserver>
  </slaveservers>
  <job-log-table>
    <connection/>
    <schema/>
    <table/>
    <size_limit_lines/>
    <interval/>
    <timeout_days/>
    <field>
      <id>ID_JOB</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ID_JOB</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>JOBNAME</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>JOBNAME</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>STATUS</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>STATUS</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_READ</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_READ</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>ERRORS</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ERRORS</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>STARTDATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>STARTDATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>ENDDATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ENDDATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOGDATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LOGDATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>DEPDATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>DEPDATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>REPLAYDATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>REPLAYDATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>EXECUTING_USER</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>EXECUTING_USER</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>START_JOB_ENTRY</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>START_JOB_ENTRY</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>CLIENT</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>CLIENT</name>
    </field>
  </job-log-table>
  <jobentry-log-table>
    <connection/>
    <schema/>
    <table/>
    <timeout_days/>
    <field>
      <id>ID_BATCH</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ID_BATCH</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOG_DATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LOG_DATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>JOBNAME</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>TRANSNAME</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>JOBENTRYNAME</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>STEPNAME</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_READ</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_READ</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_WRITTEN</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_WRITTEN</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_UPDATED</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_UPDATED</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_INPUT</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_INPUT</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_OUTPUT</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_OUTPUT</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LINES_REJECTED</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LINES_REJECTED</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>ERRORS</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ERRORS</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>RESULT</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>RESULT</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>NR_RESULT_ROWS</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>NR_RESULT_ROWS</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>NR_RESULT_FILES</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>NR_RESULT_FILES</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOG_FIELD</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>LOG_FIELD</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>COPY_NR</id>
      <enabled>N</enabled>
      <name>COPY_NR</name>
    </field>
  </jobentry-log-table>
  <channel-log-table>
    <connection/>
    <schema/>
    <table/>
    <timeout_days/>
    <field>
      <id>ID_BATCH</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ID_BATCH</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>CHANNEL_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>CHANNEL_ID</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOG_DATE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LOG_DATE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>OBJECT_NAME</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>OBJECT_NAME</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>OBJECT_COPY</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>OBJECT_COPY</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>FILENAME</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>FILENAME</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>OBJECT_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>OBJECT_ID</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>OBJECT_REVISION</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>OBJECT_REVISION</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name>
    </field>
  </channel-log-table>
  <pass_batchid>N</pass_batchid>
  <shared_objects_file/>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <name>Get a file with FTP</name>
      <description/>
      <type>FTP</type>
      <attributes/>
      <port>21</port>
      <servername>10.161.xx.xx</servername>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>xxx</password>
      <ftpdirectory>/sda1</ftpdirectory>
      <targetdirectory>Z:\</targetdirectory>
      <wildcard>^.*ShotData.csv$</wildcard>
      <binary>N</binary>
      <timeout>0</timeout>
      <remove>Y</remove>
      <only_new>Y</only_new>
      <active>N</active>
      <control_encoding>ISO-8859-1</control_encoding>
      <movefiles>N</movefiles>
      <movetodirectory/>
      <adddate>N</adddate>
      <addtime>N</addtime>
      <SpecifyFormat>N</SpecifyFormat>
      <date_time_format/>
      <AddDateBeforeExtension>N</AddDateBeforeExtension>
      <isaddresult>N</isaddresult>
      <createmovefolder>N</createmovefolder>
      <proxy_host/>
      <proxy_port/>
      <proxy_username/>
      <proxy_password>Encrypted </proxy_password>
      <socksproxy_host/>
      <socksproxy_port>1080</socksproxy_port>
      <socksproxy_username/>
      <socksproxy_password>Encrypted </socksproxy_password>
      <ifFileExists>ifFileExistsSkip</ifFileExists>
      <nr_limit>10</nr_limit>
      <success_condition>success_if_no_errors</success_condition>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>288</xloc>
      <yloc>160</yloc>
      <attributes_kjc/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Start</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SPECIAL</type>
      <attributes/>
      <start>Y</start>
      <dummy>N</dummy>
      <repeat>N</repeat>
      <schedulerType>0</schedulerType>
      <intervalSeconds>0</intervalSeconds>
      <intervalMinutes>15</intervalMinutes>
      <hour>2</hour>
      <minutes>0</minutes>
      <weekDay>1</weekDay>
      <DayOfMonth>1</DayOfMonth>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>176</xloc>
      <yloc>160</yloc>
      <attributes_kjc/>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <name>Success</name>
      <description/>
      <type>SUCCESS</type>
      <attributes/>
      <parallel>N</parallel>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      <nr>0</nr>
      <xloc>400</xloc>
      <yloc>160</yloc>
      <attributes_kjc/>
    </entry>
  </entries>
  <hops>
    <hop>
      <from>Start</from>
      <to>Get a file with FTP</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>Y</unconditional>
    </hop>
    <hop>
      <from>Get a file with FTP</from>
      <to>Success</to>
      <from_nr>0</from_nr>
      <to_nr>0</to_nr>
      <enabled>Y</enabled>
      <evaluation>Y</evaluation>
      <unconditional>N</unconditional>
    </hop>
  </hops>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
  <attributes/>
</job>
```